# What's the error in this pygame program?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making Pong game in pygame but it isn't complete yet. The names of variables, classes and other things in the code are in portuguese but I think that's easy to know what wich one does. The code should make two paddles move when the user wants to but it only displays the background and the paddles. I don't get any error message.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame,sys,os,time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

janela=pygame.display.set_mode((800, 533),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong!")
superficie=pygame.display.get_surface()

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

fundoFicheiro=os.path.join("Imagens","fundo2.png")
fundoImagem=pygame.image.load(fundoFicheiro).convert()

barraFicheiro=os.path.join("Imagens","barra.png")
barraImagem=pygame.image.load(barraFicheiro).convert_alpha()

def imprimirBarra(x,y):
        janela.blit(barraImagem,(x,y)) 



class barra():
    y=1
    x=1
    velocidade=1
    def subir(self):
        self.y-=self.velocidade
    def descer(self):
        self.y+=self.velocidade
    def parar(self):
        self.velocidade=0
    def comecar(self):
        self.velocidade=1      


barra1=barra()
barra1.x=5
barra1.y=superficie.get_height()/2-barraImagem.get_height()/2
barra2=barra()
barra2.velocidade=1
barra2.x=superficie.get_width()-(barraImagem.get_width()+5)
barra2.y=superficie.get_height()/2-barraImagem.get_height()/2

def interface():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_UP:
                barra2.comecar()
                barra2.subir()
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                barra2.comecar()
                barra2.descer()
            elif event.key==K_w:
                barra1.comecar()
                barra1.subir()
            elif event.key==K_s:
                barra1.comecar()
                barra1.descer()
        elif event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_UP:
                barra2.parar()
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                barra2.parar()
            elif event.key==K_w:
                barra1.parar()
            elif event.key==K_s:
                barra1.parar()




while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    janela.blit(fundoImagem,(0,0))        
    imprimirBarra(barra1.x,barra1.y)
    imprimirBarra(barra2.x,barra2.y)
    interface()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What is the problem? Be descriptive. StackOverflow isn't a place to dump your code and let others debug it for you. If you get an error message, put that in your question. If a specific thing in your program doesn't work, describe that and track it down to a specific function/line.

Comment: Sorry about not being very specific and maybe make a stupid mistake in the code. I'm new to python and pygame and this is the first time I post something in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

`pygame.event.get()` gives you all the events that occurred since the last time you called it. This loop uses all the events that are currently available. Therefore, when `interface()` is called, and it tries to `pygame.event.get()` again, there are no more events left to check for key presses (unless they happen to occur while the `janela.blit` calls are being made, but those should be very fast; not sure if Pygame will process events during those calls anyway).

Another problem is that you will only get `KEYDOWN` events when the key is pressed, *not* continuously while it is held (unless you configure it with `pygame.key.set_repeat()`, but this may interfere with the rest of your logic). So you have code set up to try to move the paddle continuously while the key is held down, but it won't actually do anything since `.subir` or `.descer` only gets called once per key press.

There are a lot of ways to fix this, but in any case you will have to re-structure things a bit. My suggestion is to have only one loop in the program that handles events, and translates them into some kind of data structure (e.g., it could have a `set` of which keys are currently pressed down, and which keys changed since last time). You might be able to simplify this with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, but beware that you can miss very quick key taps this way.